# How can I create an attribute in my Terraform plugin that accepts multiple data types

Tags: terraform

I have a data block in my plugin that I want to be able to use an any type for one of its attributes. The attribute could theoretically accept anything from strings, numbers, bools, lists, objects, etc.

Is this possible? I was looking at the TF framework customType: Plugin Development - Framework: Handling Data - Custom Types | Terraform | HashiCorp Developer but am unsure if this would be able to fit my requirements.

I know Terraform has an `any` type that can be specified for variables but I dont think it is supported in the plugin sdk or framework.

Comment: That would most likely be `interface{}`, but we would really need to see the code.

Comment: I think `interface{}` would be for GO but I dont think you can define a terraform data attribute as an `interface{}` type

Answer (score 0):

The Terraform provider protocol does allow providers to declare something equivalent to `any` as part of their schema.

However, as you noticed neither of the available SDKs currently has full support for that possibility, so currently it's not straightforward to use it without skipping the framework layer and directly implementing the wire protocol. There is a lower-level library [`terraform-plugin-go`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/hashicorp/terraform-plugin-go) that is a thin wrapper around the wire protocol, but it's considerably harder to use and I would not recommend trying this unless you are already familiar with the plugin protocol.

At the time I'm writing this there is an open issue in `terraform-plugin-framework` to support what you're describing: [Support Dynamic Type/Attributes](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-plugin-framework/issues/147). At the moment it isn't clear exactly what design would be best to fit within the rest of the structure of the framework, but sharing some details there about what exactly you are trying to do might help inform the design.

In the meantime the most typical design today is to define a string-typed attribute whose name has a `_json` suffix and then make your provider parse it as JSON. Using the `_json` suffix means that when the framework later has support for `any`-typed arguments you will be able to use the un-suffixed name for the new attribute and treat the `_json`-suffixed one as a legacy argument for backward compatibility.

Terraform's built-in `jsonencode` function means that in practice it's only a small amount of additional boilerplate to define an argument that expects JSON data:

```
  example_json = jsonencode({
    name = "Martin"
  })
```